# How can I sum the duration by key in Laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to get a summary of Appointment model hours for each Client model in my database. I wish the see the totals summed up by Client. I am going wrong somewhere because my code currently totals all the hours for individual Appointments and returns that. I wish to see it totalled by client. Here is the code:

```
        $clientHours = Appointment::with('client')
        ->whereBetween('ends_at', [$from, $to])
        ->get();            

        $results= [];           
        foreach($clientHours as $collection)
        {   
        $duration = [];     
                $date1      = $collection->starts_at; 
                $date2      = $collection->ends_at;                     
                $start      = Carbon::parse($date1);
                $end        = Carbon::parse($date2);
                $length     = $start->diffInMinutes($end)/60;
                $duration[] = $length;  
                $totalHours = array_sum($duration); 


            $results [] = [
            'name'          => $collection->client->name
            'totalHours'    => $totalHours,
            'charge'        => $collection->client->contract_rate * $totalHours,
            ];
        }


        return view('admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the sum() method on the collection after your get() call.

Comment: I need to SUM by client the difference between $date1 and $date2. These can be more than one so I need them in a foreach loop.

Comment: In that case chain get() into pipe() or map() and then sum the differences for each iteration.